# 0 as index - this is driving me crazy!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

this works:

```
subnavData = new Array(
                {"title":"PROCESS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showProcess},
                {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true},
                    {"title":"CREATIVE DIRECTION", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showBranding, "childOf":1},
                    {"title":"SOCIAL INTERACTIVE", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showOnline, "childOf":1},
                    {"title":"LIVE EVENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showLiveEvents, "childOf":1},
                    {"title":"CONTENT STRATEGY", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showPerformance, "childOf":1},
                {"title":"CASE STUDIES", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showCaseStudies},
                {"title":"CLIENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showClients}
            );
```

but this doesn't:

```
subnavData = new Array(
                {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true},
                    {"title":"CREATIVE DIRECTION", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showBranding, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"SOCIAL INTERACTIVE", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showOnline, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"LIVE EVENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showLiveEvents, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"CONTENT STRATEGY", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showPerformance, "childOf":0},
                {"title":"PROCESS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showProcess},
                {"title":"CASE STUDIES", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showCaseStudies},
                {"title":"CLIENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showClients}
            );
```

...when being processed by this function:

```
private function makeNewSubNav($data:Array):void {
            group = new Array();

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < $data.length; i++){
                var obj:Object = new Object();
                obj.active = false;
                obj.mc = new MovieClip();
                if($data[i].childOf) {
                    obj.childOf = $data[i].childOf;
                    obj.mcB = new SubMenuTopButton();
                    obj.mcB.arrow.x = -obj.mcB.arrow.width;
                    obj.mcB.txtmask.x += 10;
                    obj.mcB.y = group[obj.childOf].subMasked.height;
                    var childbg:Sprite = new Sprite();
                    childbg.graphics.beginFill(0xfdddf0, 1);
                    childbg.graphics.lineStyle();
                    childbg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,167, 21);
                    childbg.graphics.endFill();
                    obj.mcB.addChildAt(childbg, 0);
                    group[obj.childOf].subMasked.addChild(obj.mc);
                } else {
                    obj.childOf = false;
                    obj.mcB = new SubMenuTopButton();
                    navContainer.addChild(obj.mc);
                }
                obj.mc.addChild(obj.mcB);
                obj.mcB.txtmask.tf_name.text = $data[i].title;
                obj.mcB.buttonMode = true;
                obj.mcB.mouseChildren = false;
                obj.mcB.num = i;
                obj.callback = $data[i].func;
                obj.param = $data[i].param;
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navPress);
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, navOver);
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, navOut);

                if($data[i].hasChild){
                    obj.hasChild = true;
                    obj.subContainer = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMasked = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMask = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMask.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,1);
                    obj.subMask.graphics.lineStyle();
                    obj.subMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,width,1);
                    obj.subMask.graphics.endFill();
                    obj.subMask.height = 0;
                    obj.subContainer.addChild(obj.subMasked);
                    obj.subContainer.addChild(obj.subMask);
                    obj.subMasked.mask = obj.subMask;
                    obj.subContainer.y = obj.mc.height;
                    obj.mc.addChild(obj.subContainer);
                }
                group.push(obj);
            }

            group[0].active = true;

            adjustHeight();

        }
```

i know this has to do with the value zero.  i just don't know what to do.  the children are supposed to form a submenu. any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work? are you getting a error in the function?

Comment: You might want to give your question a meaningful title.  It will increase the chance of someone answering it.

Comment: no, no error in the function, but the children don't display as submenu items when "overview" is first in line, they do when it is second

Answer (score 2):

seems to me that since the childOf is 0 the `if ($data[i].childOf)` is failing

try any of these:

```
if ($data[i].hasOwnProperty('childOf')
if ($data[i].childOf != undefined)
if ($data[i].childOf != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet the problem is this line:

```
if($data[i].childOf) {
```

and your language treats 0 as equivalent to false.  So find another representation for that - maybe a negative value as the flag, or a more explicit test.